# Increasing the time constraint on EulerEquations

Tags: warning-messages, xact, variational-calculus

How can I set the `Infinity` time constraint in `EulerEquations`?
Actually, there is an error I don't have any idea about. Can you help me, please?

> Time spent on a transformation exceeded 300 seconds, and the transformation was aborted. Increasing the value of TimeConstraint option may improve the result of simplification.

Comment: Post the code (in copy and paste-able form) that you are using.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Actually the code is very complicated and cannot be copied here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes a function has a [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method) option that can be used to modify the options used by an internal function. This is not true for `EulerEquations`. So, instead you can use `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` to do this:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Simplify},
    SetOptions[Simplify, TimeConstraint -> Infinity];
    EulerEquations[..]
]
```